# Noun-adjective-noun: Can a noun phrase have an adjective in the middle?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, ambiguity, modifiers, noun-phrases

Can a noun phrase have an adjective in the middle as in the following examples?

> 1. car new tires
> 2. salad high-calorie dressing
> 3. house external wall
> 4. nitrogen fine droplets

These examples seem ungrammatical to me, but the writer (who is not a native speaker of English) says that bringing the adjective to the front of the noun phrase would be incorrect, because, for example, in number 4, the droplets are fine, not the nitrogen.

Are there any rules that govern this sort of thing? And is the potential of incorrect adjective-noun modification pointed out by the writer a legitimate issue?

Comment: Only if the "adjective" isn't really an adjective but part of the noun. You would say *the town swimming pool,* and not **the swimming town pool*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot interpose an adjective between the nouns of a noun phrase.  As the *Collins Cobuild English Grammar* states:

> When a noun group contains both an adjective and a noun modifier the
>   adjective is placed in front of the noun modifier.

In most cases the noun phrase will be correctly interpreted, but it is legitimate to be concerned about potential ambiguity. For example, most people will probably interpret *new car tires* as meaning *car tires that are new*. So if, in fact, you mean that the cars are new but not necessarily the tires then you would be best advised to say *the tires of new cars*.

Comment: Shoe is correct. The adjective cannot be interposed. As for your writer's "point" about _fine_ modifying the droplets and not the nitrogen, keep this in mind: In a noun phrase of this type, the first noun is _not really a noun_ (in a sense). It actually has an _adjectival_ function when used in this way.  In English, we can say either nitrogen droplets or droplets of nitrogen; they mean exactly the same thing. In the first version, _nitrogen_ becomes an adjective. So "fine nitrogen droplets" is grammatically equivalent to any phrase with two adjectives modifying a noun (like "big red car").

Comment: As far as ambiguity is concerned, this is far less common in real contexts, particularly in spoken language, where prosody conveys meaning. If, by _new car tires_, I really meant _the tires of a new car_ then I would give equal stress to _new_ and _car_ and make a slight pause before _tires_.

Comment: As opposed to *new car smell*.

Answer (score 3):

Since *external houses* and *fine nitrogen* don't make sense (although I suppose someone might come up with an outlandish situation where that's not the case), and 'high-calorie salad' is probably a contradiction in terms, there is no possible confusion in using

> 2' high-calorie salad dressing
>
> 3' external house wall [though context would usually allow the more
>   common 'external wall']
>
> 4' fine nitrogen droplets

Of course, new cars **are** common, but here again,

> new car tyres  [or more usually just new tyres]

would never be read as 'tyres (UK) /tires (US) belonging to new cars'.

The 'rule' in these situations is that a 'noun modifier' (noun used as / as if it were an adjective) is **always placed just before the modified noun**. (If there is more than one, associations must be examined: eg 'Famous Rugby League assistant manager is fired.'

In some cases, the 'noun modifier + modified noun' will actually appear in a dictionary as a compound noun; it would obviously be silly to stick an adjective between the component parts then:

> expensive particle board / expensive particleboard
>
> *particle expensive board

Admittedly, there are occasions where confusion could occur. Judicious use of hyphens removes ambiguities in these cases:

sweet shop-girl

sweet-shop girl

sweet sweet-shop girl [if you must]

see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83435/are-hyphens-used-for-phrases-like-more-or-less

Comment: So `fine nitrogen-droplets`

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is wrong. Compound nouns are nouns, and adjectives can modify them. This is the kind of silliness that comes from teaching people to name parts of speech and then believe they understand grammar.